# The "Go to matching pair" feature of Emmet plugin for Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, emmet

I've installed the Emmet plugin for Notepad++ from its Plugin Manager (the Python Script plugin has been installed successfully beforehand as well). It's so convenient for web development. But the ["Go to matching pair"](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/go-to-pair/) feature doesn't work for me. To make it work, are there any settings/configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **HTML Tag** Plugin.
Then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

*Procedure and example :* 
[image: Install HTML Tag Plugin]

[image]